# Initialise a Javascript object with default values for each property type

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript object:

```
data: {
  index: '',
  slides: '',
  timer: ''
}
```

I know `index` will be a number, `slides` will be an array of strings and `timer` will be the result of a `setInterval`.

Somewhere on my code I will have something like:

```
data: {
  index: 20,
  slides: ['s1', 's2'],
  timer: setInterval(() => this.data.index++, 10000)
}
```

**Question**

How should I initialise the object before knowing its values?

```
data: {
  index: 0,
  slides: [],
  timer: ????
}
```

Should I use the default value for each type?

Comment: It doesn't matter. JavaScript variables and object properties are not bound to any type. You can initialize them to `null` or zero or anything else.

Comment: Yes, it's correct that JS isn't typed so it really doesn't matter, but in case you want to rewrite to TypeScript later, or this object creation gets moved to function params, or some other refactor where the types might matter, I personally would initialize to the zero values for the expected types. But I'm voting to close because any answers to this would be opinion-based, there is no right answer. (And the zero value for a function is identity, `a => a`).

Comment: Why do you need to initialise the object at all? Don't create it until you know the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if timer will be the result of a setInterval() function, you should maybe initialize to 0  since setInterval() retrieves an id that represents the interval and you can use later to clear it, so its quite convinient to store it.

[chechk mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)!

Comment: but yeah null is also ok to me

Answer (score 1):

In terms of coding in JavaScript, it doesn't really matter, that's not going to harm your code in any possible way.

However, for example, for code readability (i.e. everyone who is going to read the code after you), you can set `index` to `0` because you know it's going to be a number, so everyone else can understand that it's going to be a number.

But, in other languages like TypeScript, it does really matter, that's what TypeScript is all about.